# How to get the size of a range in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, size, range

Using VBA, is it possible to get the size of a given range in terms of pixels or units? (I don't care which unit as I am only using it to relate to other measurements with the same unit).

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The overall dimensions of a range are in its `Width` and `Height` properties.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:H12")

Debug.Print r.Width
Debug.Print r.Height
```

Comment: Yep, just realized myself! Blindingly obvious in retrospect :-)

Comment: Side note:  I wanted to determine the range's size in columns not points.  This is `r.Columns.Count` and for rows `r.Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 6):

The [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members.aspx) object has both width and height properties, which are measured in points.