# VBA Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: vba, excel

Out of touch with vba and so i am sure its a silly mistake somewhere. Would be really helpful if someone could point that out

Code:

```
Private Function generate() As Integer

Dim source_size As Long
Dim target_size As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim source1 As Range
Dim target1 As Range

Set source1 = Worksheets("Filter").Range(C4, C6498)
Set target1 = Worksheets("30").Range(A2, AP95787)


source_size = source1.Height
target_size = target1.Height

For i = 1 To source_size Step 1
    For j = 1 To target_size Step 1
        If Application.source1.Cells(i, 1).Value = target1.Cells(j, 5).Value Then
            target1.Row(j).Select
            'Selection.Copy
            Worksheet("result").Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next j
Next i
generate = 0


End Function
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? What is the desired behavior of that code? Please take time to read this link before editing your post to improve it : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237873/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-range-in-excel to understand what is .Height properties

Comment: Probably ```Range(d, C6498)``` is not valid in this way. You could use e.g. ```Range("A1:C3")``` or ```Range(Cells(...), Cells(...))```. Maybe you wanted ```Range("C4:C6498")```?

Answer (score 3):

**First** you had an issue of declaring your ranges, `C4` as itself in VBA is considered as a variable, you need to use one these :

`[C4]` or `Range("C4")` or `Cells(4,3)` or `Cells(4,"C")`

So your lines or defining ranges should look like this :

```
Set source1 = Worksheets("Filter").Range([C4], [C6498])
Set target1 = Worksheets("30").Range(Range("A2"), Range("AP95787"))
```

**Secondly**, the `.Height` property will give you the size of the range, not the number of rows, to get the number of rows, you need to use `Range(...).Rows.Count`

```
source_size = source1.Rows.count
target_size = target1.Rows.count
```

---

Here is your full code :

```
Option Explicit
Public Function generate() As Integer
Dim source_size As Long
Dim target_size As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim source1 As Range
Dim target1 As Range

Set source1 = Worksheets("Filter").Range("C4:C6498")
Set target1 = Worksheets("30").Range("A2:AP95787")
source_size = source1.Rows.count
target_size = target1.Rows.count

For i = 1 To source_size Step 1
    For j = 1 To target_size Step 1
        If Application.source1.Cells(i, 1).Value = target1.Cells(j, 5).Value Then
            target1.Rows(j).Select
            'Selection.Copy
            Worksheets("result").Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next j
Next i
generate = 0
End Function
```