# Delete every other row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get rid of the every 2nd row in Excel.

So far my sheet looks like this:

[image]

from where I would like to remove the rows with date.

In this event I used the following code:

```
   Sub DeleteRows()
   Rows(2, 4, 6, 8, 10).EntireRow.Delete
   End Sub
```

as a trial for the first 10, although it returns the error:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

I found sth, which might help my issue:

[Excel VBA Delete Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042717/excel-vba-delete-rows)

basically I don't know how to make kinda loop for this.

The issue here:
[How to get the size of a range in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237873/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-range-in-excel)

States, that according to my error I should use the `Rows (2:10)` instead, however, I am going to lose all of them then.

Is there some simple loop for removing only every 2nd row?

Comment: For only the first 10 rows? or all rows in the spreadsheet? And just looking at your example, maybe it would also work to delete the rows that have a date in the first cell?

Comment: I have 315 rows and I want to remove every 2nd in the order: 2,,4,6,8...etc.
I just put first 10 into the code for the trial.

Comment: Yes the query, which you have shown me solved my problem :) Thank you very much